# HTML CSS margin-left and margin-right don't want to center a div

Tags: html, css

I'm learning css and html and i have this problem, where the margin-left and margin-right in the ".logo" div class don't want to center the div. Please help because i done reserch, i checked the code and everything looks good, so I have no idea whats going on.

```css
body
{
    background-color: #303030;
    color: #ffffff;

}

.wrapper
{
    width:100%;

}

.header
{
    width:100px;
    padding:40px 0;
}

.logo
{
    width:450px;
    font-size:48px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                LOGO
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that `.header` is smaller than `.logo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header is only `100px` while your logo is `450px`, you can check this [fiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6j7s9rea/).

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 450px;
  font-size: 48px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: wow because of 1 stupid zero in the code, i lost almost and hour trying to see what's wrong. Thank you very much for the fast reply:D

Comment: yeah i'm pretty new to StackOverflow:D, but sure no problem